# How do i make google firebase sent data depending on the User with my React Native to-do app, example in description

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I'm pretty new to React Native and Google Firebase, my question may be quite difficult to understand due to my little knowledge, but here is my best shot.

I'm making a advanced To-Do app and I'm saving all the data (what the user inputs like Take Dog On Walk (example)) too google firebase so when the app is fully closed it can then be opened and restored with all the users to-do items. My question is, does google firebase keep its data all together so if i have two separate people on two different devices, and Person1 puts Wash Dishes, and Person2 puts Walk Dog, will Walk Dog and Wash Dishes show up for Person1 and Person2, how can i make it so its stores the data only for that device, and displays Wash Dishes for only Person1, but also store Person2's data but just for him?

sorry if this is a really obvious answer like it automatically does it etc,

Comment: are you familiar with DBMS Systems or not? cause i need to know about this to help you out

Comment: @Abilogos i know how to add firebase too react native just through basic videos and add and edit and make it update but apart from that, not much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not going to mixed up.

Since you will be create a path for each user like this:

```
/users/$uid
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#how_data_is_structured_its_a_json_tree

and give any user to write on their own path with authorization

Further information on Authentication and Authorization:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security